# Сортировка SimpleXML

Tags: php, curl, soap, simplexml

Написал такой код, сам запрос взял из Postman

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'https://ucn.ucm.ru:8443/axl/',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>'<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns="http://www.cisco.com/AXL/API/14.0">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ns:getPhoneButtonTemplate sequence="?">
         <uuid>{5CB1EDA8-35EE-A225-D13F-F13A8497E61E}</uuid>
         <returnedTags uuid="?">
            <name/>
            <isUserModifiable>?</isUserModifiable>
            <buttons>
               <button uuid="?">
                  <buttonNumber/>
                  <feature/>
                  <label/>
               </button>
            </buttons>
         </returnedTags>
      </ns:getPhoneButtonTemplate>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>',
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'Authorization: Basic hzkfjasfkrucskasdasldhfsallkvdfsa==',
    'Content-Type: text/plain',
    'Cookie: JSESSIONID=DHSDFLSLFLVHSGTDLTKVND; JSESSIONIDSSO=ZCCDFPVJDGJF'
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($response);
$phone_a = $xml->xpath('//phoneButtonTemplate')[0];
$phone_b = $xml->xpath('//button');


$Count = count($phone_b);
echo "UUID is: " . $phone_a['uuid'] . "\n";
echo "Template: " . $phone_a->name . "\n";
echo "Количество кнопок в шаблоне: $Count \n";

for ($i = 0; $i < $Count; $i++) {
//   echo $phone_b[$i]->buttonNumber . "\n";
//   echo $phone_b[$i]->label . "\n";
//   echo $phone_b[$i]->feature . "\n";
   $buttonNumber = $phone_b[$i]->buttonNumber; 
   $label = $phone_b[$i]->label;
   $feature = $phone_b[$i]->feature;
   if ($feature == 'None')
      continue;
   else
      echo $buttonNumber . ' ' . $label . ' ' . $feature . "\n";
}

?>
```

Он делает все что мне нужно за исключением сортировки по $buttonNumber:

```
UUID is: {5CB1EDA8-35EE-A225-D13F-F13A8497E61E}
Template: Cst 9951 SIP - 1 Line/MOB/DND/2SURL/1x36BLF
Количество кнопок в шаблоне: 77 
41 Speed Dial BLF Speed Dial BLF
40 Speed Dial BLF Speed Dial BLF
39 Speed Dial BLF Speed Dial BLF
38 Speed Dial BLF Speed Dial BLF
37 Speed Dial BLF Speed Dial BLF
36 Speed Dial BLF Speed Dial BLF
35 Speed Dial BLF Speed Dial BLF
34 Speed Dial BLF Speed Dial BLF
33 Speed Dial BLF Speed Dial BLF
32 Speed Dial BLF Speed Dial BLF
31 Speed Dial BLF Speed Dial BLF
30 Speed Dial BLF Speed Dial BLF
28 Speed Dial BLF Speed Dial BLF
27 Speed Dial BLF Speed Dial BLF
26 Speed Dial BLF Speed Dial BLF
25 Speed Dial BLF Speed Dial BLF
```

Прошу показать как сделать в этом случае сортировку по первой колонке ($buttonNumber). У меня также не получилось сделать итерацию через forache и пришлось использовать for, буду благодарен если и это как то объясните

Comment: какая версия php?

Comment: версия PHP 8.1.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сортировка массива

```
usort($phone_b, fn($a, $b) => (int)$a->buttonNumber <=> (int)$b->buttonNumber);
```

после этого оператора массив будет упорядочен по возрастанию

---

foreach

```
foreach($phone_b as $phone) {
   $feature = $phone->feature;
   if ($feature == 'None')
      continue;
   $buttonNumber = $phone->buttonNumber; 
   $label = $phone->label;
   echo "{$buttonNumber} {$label} {$feature}\n";
}
```

Comment: что значит не работает - возможно поле строковое, а не числовое - тогда надо преобразовывать в числа перед сравнением. Если это  так, то должны получаться упорядоченными по первому символу

Comment: да, строковые ["buttonNumber"]=>string(2) "56"

Comment: я привел пример, как должно работать при строковых

Comment: заработало вот так **usort($phone_b, fn($a, $b) => $a->buttonNumber - $b->buttonNumber);**

Comment: кораблик поменял на минус